# Future builder with page transition cause lag

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-futurebuilder, materialpageroute

I have some troubles in my applications since I'm using different animated widget in combination of Future Builder (I think this is the problem).

For example when I perform a navigation to another page and in this page I retrieve data with future builder, the page transitions lag. This is an example:

[image: Babou]

As you can see the animation is lagging at the end. But I'm not sure that is a problem with Future Builder and the transitions.

This example was made on a release application on iOS, so not in debug mode.